# Sharing Ehcache across web apps in same webserver?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

i am using single weblogic which host two web application. I am using spring container and below is my Ehcache configuration

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
     <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    <property name="shared" value="true" />
</bean>
```

As i mentioned shared attribute as true, i was expecting there will be single cache manager and  single cache .**But i can see two customerCache
elements in memory separate for each application. How can i make it truly singleton per jvm with spring across application ?**

for example

```
   <cache name="customerCache" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you will have to share a common Ehcache `CacheManager` between your two applications.

For Ehcache, this means having the `CacheManager` loaded by the same class loader in both applications.

Ways to achieve this are:

- Find a way to share a Spring context between your two applications (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769909/spring-share-web-application-context-between-different-webapps)) or
- Move Ehcache library to a shared lib system which will give you the shared cache loader, and then make sure its initialisation is properly handled by either webapps (but not both)